# How to make an authenticated POST with parameters in body and in URL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

Due to server constraints, I need to make a `POST` that includes parameters in both the URL and the body.  I'm using `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`'s `HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest` method to accomplish this, as I can initialize the URL request with the URL params like:

`NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:components.URL];`

And then I can separately set the body of the `POST` like:

`[request setHTTPBody:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];`

The problem arises when I've set the `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`'s `requestSerializer` to use an Authorization header token.  The request comes back as a `401 unauth`.  However, if I set the request object's header directly like:

`[request setValue:self.accessToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];`

The call succeeds.  Anyone know of a better way to make an authenticated call that sends parameters simultaneously in the body and the URL of the `POST`?  My implementation seems less than ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you need to support iOS6, I think you should move to using AFHTTPSessionManager instead of AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.

Subclass AFHTTPSessionManager and override:

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                               uploadProgress:(void (^)(NSProgress * _Nonnull))uploadProgressBlock
                             downloadProgress:(void (^)(NSProgress * _Nonnull))downloadProgressBlock
                            completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error))completionHandler {

    NSMutableURLRequest *modifiedRequest = request.mutableCopy;    
    NSString *token = [Get your access token];

    [modifiedRequest addValue:token forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    // Now set up the data task as normal
    return [super dataTaskWithRequest:modifiedRequest
                       uploadProgress:uploadProgressBlock
                     downloadProgress:downloadProgressBlock
                    completionHandler:completionHandler];
}
```

It results in the same as your approach (I'm not aware of a better way) - but ensures it happens automatically for all calls.

Initialise your session manager as an instance of your subclass.

Then using AFNetworking's POST method, set up your parameters and go:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"Param1":param1 ? param1 : @"",
                         @"Param2":param2 ? param2 : @""};

[self.sessionManager
 POST:self.serviceEndpointUrl
 parameters:params
 etc..
```